# How to use' Future Continuous Tense ' for parallel actions in future?

Tags: tense

For example
I am going to be cooking food and he is going to be washing dishes in the next month party.

OR

I am going to be cooking food while he washes dishes in the next month party.

Are both the sentences correct ?

Comment: You need to fix 'next month party'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both sentences are nearly correct ('in the next month party' is wrong), but they mean different things:

I am going to do something and another person is going to do something else at some place - nothing is said about whether we do those things at the same time.

I am going to do something while another person does something else at some place - I am going to do something at some place, but only during the time that the other person is doing something else at the same place. He starts, I start; he stops; I stop.